# Formatting Related Error

Tags: java, formatting

This was originally one line, but I wanted to format the percentage and when I replaced it, I got errors, so I did this instead (It displays how I like), but I was wondering what the correct way would be to do it? Hopefully, it will help me to understand why whatever I did before did not work.

```
System.out.print("\nThe "+oracleStock.name+"'s change is ");
System.out.printf("%3.2f",oracleStock.getChangePercent());
System.out.print("%");
```

Thank you for your help, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `printf`, you can't use a `%` to represent `%`, because a `%` means that what follows is a field specifier. If you really want to put a `%` in your format, you use a double percent, like so:

```
System.out.printf("%nThe %s's change is %3.2f%%", oracleStock.name, oracleStock.getChangePercent());
```

By the way, instead of `\n` in `printf`, you should use `%n` because the latter will print the correct line separator depending on the platform.